# Symfony2 - Blog & Comment system - How to persist a Comment

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning how to make a basic Blog in Symfony2 and have come to a standstill when it comes to adding the comment system.

So far I can view the blog entries fine. Under a single blog post I am using Twig to render a form directly from a Controller:

```
{% render "PaulDemoBundle:Default:addComment" with { 'id': blog_entry.id } %}
```

As you can see I am populating the ID with the Id of the blog being viewed, in order to allow me to correctly attach the comment to the blog entry.

Below is the Action in my Controller:

```
public function addCommentAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $add_comment = new Comment();
    $add_comment->setBlogId($id);

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($add_comment)
            ->add('blog_id', 'hidden')
            ->add('author', 'text')
            ->add('comment', 'textarea')
            ->getForm();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $comment = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_index'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PaulDemoBundle:Default:add_comment.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'id' => $id));
}
```

here you can see that the Controller can pickup the Request data and the blog_id ($id). The form is generated with a hidden field that holds the blog_id.

Viewing the form HTML source, you get this:

```
<form action="/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/add_comment/3" method="post" >

<div id="form">
<input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="d4adb511709259d0df921a0a1b969cee0df83630" />
<input type="hidden" id="form_blog_id" name="form[blog_id]" value="3" />
<div><label for="form_author" class=" required">Author</label><input type="text" id="form_author" name="form[author]" required="required" value="" /></div>
<div><label for="form_comment" class=" required">Comment</label><textarea id="form_comment" name="form[comment]" required="required"></textarea></div></div>
<input type="submit" />
```

Again, you can see that the blog_id has been passed through (3).

Now, filling in the Author and Comment and hitting Submit, I get an error. It seems to think the blog_id is NULL. I have done a var_dump (and commented out the persist stuff) and the form request data shows that the blog_id is set to 3.

I even typecast $id to (int) as the form data shows it as a string (this shouldnt be a problem as it should be made an INT when it is persisted to the DB.

Can anyone see the problem?

Basically I have a M:1 Comment:Blog relationship and I need to somehow tell the application what blog is being viewed and pass along the ID (which I am doing atm, but it's broken ofc!)

edit: the var_dump:

```
object(Paul\DemoBundle\Entity\Comment)#67 (6) { 
["id":"Paul\DemoBundle\Entity\Comment":private]=> NULL 
["blog_id":"Paul\DemoBundle\Entity\Comment":private]=> string(1) "3"
["blog":"Paul\DemoBundle\Entity\Comment":private]=> NULL 
["author":"Paul\DemoBundle\Entity\Comment":private]=> string(8) "Mr Jones" 
["comment":"Paul\DemoBundle\Entity\Comment":private]=> string(4) "test"
["created":"Paul\DemoBundle\Entity\Comment":private]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Why not using a bundle for comments? [FriendsOfSymfony / FOSCommentBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle) - Maybe your features are already in and/or you can learn from the code. [Docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/31f4c02fb6aace429f24f4739429c98326c6b30c/Resources/doc/index.rst)

Comment: Very plausible, but I am pretty darn new to Symfony2 and I am trying to build things from scratch to get a feel for this Framework. Don't get me wrong, I will most likely use the various pre-made bundles when it comes to actual development of applications, but for now, I need to figure out this silly problem! :)

Comment: If you want to code yourself (and you don't even want to learn from exisiting code), check Symfony docs, they have hands-on examples which will tell you how to just do persistance: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/index.html

Comment: Finally got it figured out. Just had to get the blog entry via GetRepository and use that to link the comment and blog together.

Comment: Please add it as an answer to your question. You can then accept it after some time. That will mark the question as solved and could be helpful for others having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it figured out. Just had to get the blog entry via GetRepository and use that to link the comment and blog together.